# HTML tags are stripped off from emails

Tags: 6, emails, theming

I am using HTML Mail, Emogrifier, Pathologic and Echo modules to theme the outgoing Drupal emails into a template based presentation.

So far, I guess it has not been too hard, but I am having a hard time getting the HTML Mail test message to allow HTML. I am using the Full HTML filter on the test message edit, and using Unfiltered for Post filter setting.

I get my test message, but its stripped of `<h>` tags and `<p>` tags and anything that isn't an anchor, `<code>`, `<span>`, or list. Does anyone know why?

I tried editing various filter formats and nothing affected it. It would seem like it keeps using Filtered HTML no matter what I select, but even still, it is not showing `<h>` tags and `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im thinking your input format is filtering out the HTML Tags, As DanielGT Said, add a new input format that would allow using HTML tags, or just install a WYSIWYG editor, I personally prefer tinyMCE.

Answer (score 1):

My Drupal setup relies on some other modules, but otherwise I have the same set up. I am not an expert (critics, take note!), but have you tried creating a new input format which ONLY contains the emogrifier filter?
I have all my standard filters in one input format that gets applied to all content types, and then I have a seperate input format which applies emogrifier as the post-filtering process in HTML Mail.
Just a suggestion. Daniel.